# Allow value -1 when clicking on a button and link, but just one time (the first time clicked upon) without disabling the button/link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script:

```
<script language=javascript>
    function process(v){
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('v').value);
        value+=v;
        document.getElementById('v').value = value;
    }
</script>


<input type=test size=10 id='v' name='v' value='3'>
<input type=button value='-' onclick='javascript:process(-1)'>
<a id="v" href="#" onclick='javascript:process(-1)'>minus</a>
```

If you click the button, it will deduct 1 from the total amount (3). The same applies for the minus-link. Now this all works great.

The problem is that I want to allow each one to deduct 1, just one time. Without disabling the button/link.

Example what I need:
So I click the button: 3 -> 2. 
Now I click the button again, nothing will happen 2 stays 2. 
Now I click the minus-link, 2 -> 1. 
Clicking the link again, nothing will happen 1 stays 1

This can all be mixed of course. The main thing is, they each are allowed to do the -1 just one time (the first time clicked upon).

How to do this?

Kind regards,
Maurice

Comment: General idea: set a global Boolean value after the first time, and test it every time.

Comment: curious as to why you are opposed to disabling / hiding the button / link?

Comment: I cannot disable the button because the have other functions as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is tagged under jQuery, I provide you a way do do it in jQuery! Using this could help you in the long run to get a cleaner code and to fix future problems like this ;)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NtHwN/4/

```
<input size=10 id="sum" value="3">
<input class="minus" type=button value="-">
<a class="minus" href="#">minus</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".minus").one("click", function(){
        var value = parseInt($("#sum").val());
        $("#sum").val(value -1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this one as well

Comment: Went for this solution since most others disable the onclick (which I still need after the first click). Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 1):

First: You don't need the `javascript:`-prefix in an onclick attribute.

You can achieve your desired behaviour by removing the `onclick` method on click, as shown below, and in this **fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XPHLU/1/**

```
<script>
function process(v, elem){
    if(elem && elem.onclick){
        elem.onclick = null;
    }
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('v').value);
    value+=v;
    document.getElementById('v').value = value;
}
</script>

<input type=test size=10 id='v' name='v' value='3'>
<input type=button value='-' onclick='process(-1, this);'>
<a id="v" href="#" onclick='process(-1, this)'>minus</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language=javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#negativeButton, #v").one("click", {arg: -1}, function(event){
//.one() registers a 'click' event, execute it once, and unbind it.  
//stop propagation to the other click events.      
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
//stop from moving to href="" 
        event.preventDefault();
        process(event.data.arg, this);
    });
//optionally, you can register a .click() after this as well for the same buttons.  .one() will only remove that 'one' click event.

});
    function process(v){
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('v').value);
        value+=v;
        document.getElementById('v').value = value;
    }
</script>


<input type=test size=10 id='v' name='v' value='3'>
<input id="negativeButton" type="button" value='-' >
<a id="v" href="#">minus</a>
```

Comment: Not for this part, but other scripts use jQuery on the page so it is loaded anyway :)

Comment: @Steve it's tagged as a jQuery question, so I gave the option ;).  All solutions on the page have the same solution design, so they all work.

Comment: @Maurice it may be important that the .one() event registers before any other .click() events.  The comments to add other click events after the .one() event is registered was intentional

Comment: @DefyGravity - From the code in the page, there was no evidence of jQuery being used - document.getElementById() calls etc.. I assumed it was a mis-tagging.

Comment: @all went for IntoTheVoid's solution. Thanks for the help! ps I added the jquery tag cause I wanted to give you guys more solution options then just javascript since jquery was loaded on my page anyway. Will make this more clear next time

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type=button value='-' onclick='javascript:process(-1)' id="button-to-click">
```

Remove the click handler:

```
   function process(v){
     var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('v').value);
     value+=v;
     document.getElementById('v').value = value;
     document.getElementById('button-to-click').onclick = null;
    }
```

or for multiple

```
<input type=button value='-' onclick='javascript:process(this, -1)'>
```

Remove the click handler:

```
   function process(obj, v){
     var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('v').value);
     value+=v;
     document.getElementById('v').value = value;
     obj.onclick = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... this one should work. JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5gE6d/5/).

HTML (with minor changes):

```
<input type=test size=10 id='v' name='v' value='3'></input>
<input id="i" type=button value='Minus'></button>
<a id="l" href="javascript://">minus</a>
```

*Note: I do not necessarily recommend using `javascript://`.*

JavaScript:

```
function appendEvent(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', (function() {
        var clicked = false;
        var inputEl = document.getElementById('v');
        return function() {
            if (!clicked) {
                var value = parseInt(inputEl .value);
                inputEl.value = --value;
                clicked = true;
            };
        };
    }()));
}

appendEvent('i');
appendEvent('l');
```